# ASP NET Angular 4 App takes long to restore packages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I create an ASP.NET Core Web Application, with **Angular** template, it takes very long to restore packages. Can anyone suggests why is it so? I've waited for over an hour now and its still not restoring packages.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

It worked by running **npm install** command from command prompt.

The "Restore Packages" menu option from visual-studio 2017 was not working and yellow warning sign was appearing against npm packages. I opened Node.Js command prompt and run the **npm install** command and npm packages got restored like a charm. Please find the attached screen shot.

[image]